# LazReport design view is blank

Tags: report, lazarus

Yesterday I created a LazReport (Lazarus) and when I open the design view now, it's just empty (white sheet). Nothing else - no bands, no objects.

However, when I run the code, I see the report correctly.

Have I done something wrong to make the components disappear? Please advise.

This is how I created the report:
1. Placed data components (connection, transaction, query) and set all at design time to be able to open the DB.

1. Placed a TfrDBDataSet component and LazReport.
2. Removed the visual components for connection, transaction and query.
3. Inserted code for the components I removed so that they can share the same connection and stuff.
4. All worked fine. I even moved the Lazarus project from Ubuntu to Windows and all was fine.
5. Now I just tried to open the project for editing the report. But the components show blank. The lrf file HAS contents in it.

I just placed a new band and that shows fine. But none of the actual stuff.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure if this is right, but I was able to get the report back. I took the report designer and selected OPEN REPORT. It was back. Is this normal behaviour or is there another way of doing this?